# Django UserCreationForm and Bootstrap Forms Layouts

Tags: python, django, bootstrap-5

I am trying to extend the `UserCreationForm` using a Bootstrap layout style for the field `username`. After the `input` tag in the registration form, I would like to add a `div` element like an example that I have readapted from the Bootstrap page: i.e. suggesting the user to enter the same username as the company domain.

Let's focus to the bare minimum. The form readapted from Bootstrap is:

```
<form class="row gy-2 gx-3 align-items-center method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %} ">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="your.username" id="id_username">
      <div class="input-group-text">@company.domain.com</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Which produces the following:

[image]

For the moment, I am using only `{{form.as_p}}` in my html template file:

```
<form class="row gy-2 gx-3 align-items-center method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %} ">
  {{form.as_p}}
  <div class="col-auto">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

And I don't know how to add the `<div class="input-group-text">@company.domain.com</div>` part embedded in a `<div class="input-group">...</div>` block.

My actual `forms.py` is a bit more complex, but readapted for this minimum example it contains the widget attributes as follows:

```
class SignupForm(UserCreationForm):    
    username = forms.CharField(label="",
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'your.username'}))
    
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
        )
```

Without additional libraries, is there a way to extend the widget attributes? Is it even possible to use `{{form.as_p}}` as I am currently doing or should I use another method?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use only `{{ form.as_p }}` with bootstrap then you need to install `django-bootstrap`.

Install it using pip:

```
pip install django-bootstrap4
```

After installation, add it in `INSTALLED_APPS` in settings.py file.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   'bootstrap4',
]
```

And in templates, you need to load it.

```
{% load bootstrap4 %}
{% bootstrap_messages %}
<form class="row gy-2 gx-3 align-items-center method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %} ">

  {% csrf_token %}
  
  {% bootstrap_form form %} # added `form` here. we don't need to use with as_p.

  <div class="form-group">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is the way you can use bootstrap along with `{{ form.as_p }}`

**OR**

Try another way:

Simply you can use `{{ form.username }}` inside an input tag in template.

For Example:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ form.username }}">


<form class="row gy-2 gx-3 align-items-center method="POST" action="{% url 'register' %} ">
  <div class="col-auto">
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="your.username" id="id_username" value="{{ form.username }}"> #Added here
      <div class="input-group-text">@company.domain.com</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-auto">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This definitely works. While my simple example is addressing only `username`, in my actual form I have also have first name, last name, email, password 1 and 2. I am wondering if there is something simpler.

Comment: What exactly how you want

Comment: I would like to extend the `UserCreationForm` having more control on the `input` tag, i.e. not only passing `class="form-control"` but more - but I'm not sure if it is possible. And in the html, I would like to use only `{{form.as_p}}` - not sure if possible too.

Comment: If you want to use only {{form.as_p}} along with bootstrap then you need to install bootstrap tag and need to load it in template

Comment: I have updated my answer according to your last comment. Try that. and it should work perfect.

Comment: Upvoted, because the answer is useful and a very interesting approach. Still, my requirement was without an external library. In any case, I am open to learn that what I am asking fore is not possible.